# extension wont work as soon as started

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am learning how to make chrome extensions and for my extension to work on every tab i have added the following event listeners in background.js:
tabs.onActivated, tabs.onCreated, tabs.onUpdated, and browserAction.onClicked(this one is used to change the flag am sending in message every time the extension button is pressed)
for all these events i send a message to one of the content script js file and that file changes some content according to the recieved message.

Problem is: If i start chrome and the extension isn't active yet, on activating the extension i need to refresh all the opened tabs for it to work otherwise it doesn't send any messages to the content script of the opened tabs, even on clicking the extension icon.
Is there a way by which the extension can start working immediately as i start it without the need of refresh?

Comment: Get the list of all tabs, then run the content script in each tab using chrome.tabs.executeScript. There are many examples, here's one: [Chrome extension content script re-injection after upgrade or install](//stackoverflow.com/q/10994324)

Comment: worked!! yeye ^_^ thanx :)